# How to call more than one GET method on ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Doing my first steps with ASP.NET Web API I am trying to develop an api that handles forum posts.

In the `PostsController` I have the following method, that I can invoke using 'localhost/api/posts':

```
    public IEnumerable<__PostModel> GetPosts()
```

Now I have also this method, which I invoke using: 'localohost/api/posts/5':

```
    public string GetPosts(int id)
```

Now I need another method which returns a range of posts:

```
    public IEnumerable<__PostModel> GetRange(int from, int to)
```

I can't figure out how to call it. I'm trying 'localohost/api/posts?from=5&to=8' and it always call the GetPosts() method. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is called `GetRange` and your URL's endpoint is `posts`. It won't find it. Renaming the method to `GetPosts` (thus creating a third overload) should work.

```
public IEnumerable<__PostModel> GetPosts(int from, int to)
```